# LoRa ESP32 V2 board ("Core 1 panic'ed")

Tags: arduino, esp32, lora, lorawan

I just received 2 LoRa ESP32 boards that I ordered just for fun testing. However, one of them has a weird issue. Having the "factory-example" the board comes with, one of them works just fine, while the other one never appears to fully boot. Instead, I get this in the serial output:

"Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)."

It just keeps on rebooting.

Is there something physically wrong with the board or how am I supposed to handle this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that the interrupt watchdog times out. As a result the ESP32 restarts. However, because the watchdog times out the ESP32 keeps restarting. (And that goes pretty fast.)

The error message means that an interrupt is blocked too long for some reason. This can be due to a software issue (i.e. a bug). In that case you can try to upload some simple code (e.g. a standard Hello World/blink example) to the board and check if that solves the problem. If that doesn't work, it probably is a hardware problem. In that case, the problem is probably not easy/possible to fix and you should contact your vendor.

For more information about watchdogs on the ESP32, see [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/wdts.html).

Comment: Okay. The thing is, i flashed identical software to my two boards. One of them works fine, while the other one has this issue. A simple blink program still works though. It seems like the issue occurs when I try to use the LoRa module onboard.

Comment: In that case it seems likely to me that it is a hardware problem, possibly somewhere in a critical section. If you want to figure out what the problem is you could look in the backtrace where the problems occurs (you may need to change the CONFIG_ESP_SYSTEM_PANIC (https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/kconfig.html#config-esp-system-panic) setting for that.